# Run a program at startup after starting display services

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, x11

I have written a script that uses the `import` command. I want to start it when user logins. I put path of the script in `/etc/profile` but because it starts before starting gnome I get errors and can't even login.

I also tried putting that in `~/.xinitrc` but that doesn't seem to launch at all.

I use Arch. Where should I put the path of script in order to start after all graphical services has been started?

Answer (score 0):

/etc/profile is system-wide. If you want to use it for one user, use ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile. It would be best if you would tell us what the script should do and how it does look like.